# 404 NOT FOUND in laravel 8, defined controller does not exit

Tags: routes, view, controller

I have the error, 404 NOT FOUND.

I think i have correctly defined my routes and controllers.

I have my controllers inside Http/Controllers/Admin/Auth.

Here is my route:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

/*======================
  ADMIN ROUTES
========================*/
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin'], function () {

    Route::group(['namespace' => 'Auth'], function () {

        Route::get('/signup', 'SignupController@signupForm')->name('signup-admin');
        Route::post('/signup', 'SignupController@signup')->name('signup-admin');

        Route::get('/login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login-admin');
        Route::post('/login', 'LoginController@login')->name('login-admin');

        Route::get('/forgot-password', 'ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.request');
        Route::post('/forgot-password', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail')->name('password.request');

        Route::get('/reset-password/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm')->name('password.reset');
        Route::post('/reset-password/{token}', 'ResetPasswordController@reset')->name('password.reset');
    });
});
```

And my controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SignupController extends Controller
{
    public function signupForm() {
        return view('admin.auth.signup');
    }

    public function signup() {
        return view('admin.auth.signup');
    }
}
```

so I am trying to access, http://127.0.0.1:8000/signup

when i comment out the routes above and do this one:

```
Route::get('/signup', function () {
    return view('admin/auth/signup');
});
```

i am then able to see my signup page. of course this is not how i want it.

When i run `php artisan route:list`, i have Target class [Admin\Auth\SignupController] does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

i solved the problem by adding to app/providers/routeserviceproviders, `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';` and it works fine now.